# How to filter data and print out string using python beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.brothersoft.com/synthfont-159403.html'
pageHtml = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageHtml)

for a in soup.select('div.Updated.coLeft ul a[href]'):
    print a.string
```

But it give me this output:

```
Kenneth Rundt
```

What I need is the whole information inside the updated coleft class.
What should I do?

Comment: What do you want to be printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get `li` elements:

```
>>> for li in soup.select('div.Updated.coLeft li'):
...     print ' '.join(li.stripped_strings)
... 
Last Updated: Dec 27, 2012
License: Freeware Free
OS: Windows 7/Vista/XP
Requirements: No special requirements
Publisher: Kenneth Rundt (4 more Applications)
```

Comment: @falsetruHow can I only want to output like this:
Last Updated: Dec 27, 2012
Publisher: Kenneth Rundt

Comment: @falsetruI tried this:
for a in soup.select('div.class1.coLeft a[href]'):
        print "Last Updated: "+soup.find("time")["datetime"]

I get the date but I dont have how to get the publisher name